# Connection_time_out error when trying to access my wordpress site - tried all solutions

Tags: wordpress, server, web-hosting, connection-timeout

I have a website that is hosted with gandi, the website was only showing initially for the wordpress admin and anyone who was not an admin could not see the website. After I tried somewhat haphazardly to find solutions, the website got completely disabled with a connection_timed_out error and I don't know if this was due to my actions. I remember disabling and enabling DNS records, Disabling and enabling DNSSEC. Deleting my HTTPS free SSL certificate and requesting another. I've reuploaded a version of the website that is from a week before the problem occurred using FTP a couple of days ago but the problem still persists. I now only have access through FTP and have deactivated all the plugins, renamed all the theme folders so Wordpress defaults to the original theme. I've increased the memory limit on wp-config.php file by adding 'define( 'WP_MEMORY_LIMIT', '64M' );' at the end, set the debug mode to true in that same file and I've also added'php_value max_execution_time 60' in .htaccess file but to no avail the website continues to give the connection timed out error.

I also bought the domain as deeraadesign.com, I remember the website completely crashing after I changed the site url on wordpress to deeraadesign.com from www.deeraadesign.com and I'm thinking that may have thrown off wordpress and now it is redirecting back and forth to a domain that is not the wordpress website? maybe DNSSEC destroyed the domain? Maybe I have too many themes on the website even though I have tried to deactivate them? I just don't know and all the solutions online are the saying the same things that I have already tried and not telling me anything new.

I mean, I have around 5 websites on gandi but it can't be the memory limit either as my hosting company says I only have 7GB/20GB and it also says my website is published and accessible?? so the problem is on Wordpress's end? Any help would be very much appreciated...

Thank you,
Hameed

Comment: Hello.  Your question is difficult to answer, and is more than likely considered off topic. https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask

Answer (score 0):

Try this

add

php_value max_execution_time 300

in .htaccess file

Hope it will work